# MATLAB - Classification output

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, classification, bayesian, k-means

My programme uses K-means clustering of a set amount of clusters from the user. For this k=4 but I would like to run the clustered information through matlabs naive bayes classifier afterwards.

Is there a way to split the clusters up and feed them into different naive classifiers in matlab?

Naive Bayes:

```
class  = classify(test,training, target_class, 'diaglinear');
```

K-means:

```
    %% generate sample data
K = 4;
numObservarations = 5000;
dimensions = 42;
%% cluster
opts = statset('MaxIter', 500, 'Display', 'iter');
[clustIDX, clusters, interClustSum, Dist] = kmeans(data, K, 'options',opts, ...
'distance','sqEuclidean', 'EmptyAction','singleton', 'replicates',3);
%% plot data+clusters
figure, hold on
scatter3(data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,3), 5, clustIDX, 'filled')
scatter3(clusters(:,1),clusters(:,2),clusters(:,3), 100, (1:K)', 'filled')
hold off, xlabel('x'), ylabel('y'), zlabel('z')
%% plot clusters quality
figure
[silh,h] = silhouette(data, clustIDX);
avrgScore = mean(silh);
%% Assign data to clusters
% calculate distance (squared) of all instances to each cluster centroid
D = zeros(numObservarations, K);     % init distances
for k=1:K
%d = sum((x-y).^2).^0.5
D(:,k) = sum( ((data - repmat(clusters(k,:),numObservarations,1)).^2), 2);
end
% find  for all instances the cluster closet to it
[minDists, clusterIndices] = min(D, [], 2);
% compare it with what you expect it to be
sum(clusterIndices == clustIDX)
```

something like outputing k clusters to a format k1,k2,k3 then having the naive classifier pick those up, instead of test it would be k1,k2.. etc

```
class  = classify(k1,training, target_class, 'diaglinear');
```

But I just dont know how to send the output of the k clusters in matlab to some type of format? (really new to this programme)

**EDIT**

```
training = [1;0;-1;-2;4;0]; % this is the sample data.
target_class = ['posi';'zero';'negi';'negi';'posi';'zero'];% This should have the same number of rows as training data. The elements and the class on the same row should correspond.
% target_class are the different target classes for the training data; here 'positive' and 'negetive' are the two classes for the given training data

% Training and Testing the classifier (between positive and negative)
test = 10*randn(10,1) % this is for testing. I am generating random numbers.
class  = classify(test,training, target_class, 'diaglinear')  % This command classifies the test data depening on the given training data using a Naive Bayes classifier

% diaglinear is for naive bayes classifier; there is also diagquadratic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
% create 100 random points (this is the training data)
X = rand(100,3);

% cluster into 5 clusters
K = 5;
[IDX, C] = kmeans(X, K);

% now let us say you have new data and you want 
% to classify it based on the training:
SAMPLE = rand(10,3);
CLASS = classify(SAMPLE,X,IDX);
```

And if you just want to filter out one of the clusters out of the data you can do something like that:

```
K1 = X(IDX==1)
```

Hope that was helpful..

Comment: Zenpoy thanks a bunch! However as you use SAMLE as the test data wouldnt you use K1? Or have I confused test,training, target_class? I thought target_class would be the labels for each classified rows, trainning would be specific data to learn how to recognise, and test data would be the first sample data to verfiy if it can classify what your looking for? (i.e one of the clusters for my specific problem)

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you confused something. According to the documentation `help classify`: CLASS = classify(SAMPLE,TRAINING,GROUP) classifies each row of the data in SAMPLE into one of the groups in TRAINING.  SAMPLE and TRAINING must be matrices with the same number of columns.  GROUP is a grouping variable for TRAINING.  Its unique values define groups, and each element defines which group the corresponding row of TRAINING belongs to. GROUP can be a categorical variable, numeric vector, a string array, or a cell array of strings.

Comment: Ah wait there is multiple choices yes you can group them but you can also individually classify them as well. See my above edit code. Notice I train them with training data and use the target class to classify them. Then I "test" the classifier with random numbers. The output is class with the classified positive and negative numbers. In my example I would simply use one of my clusters as the test mechanism.

Comment: @Garrith - I still don't understand why would you want to "test" the classifier against one of the kmeans clusters. if your data training data is: [-100 -1 1 2] and your labels are [neg neg pos pos] the 2-means algorithm will classify it as [1 2 2 2]. are you expecting that your classifier will produce "error" on label 2?

Comment: Its due to a more complex system im developing, the above are just examples bud. Not intended for real use. Im trying a multi classification system out, certain algorithms are more adept at identifying characteristics than others. For example I first test data on kmeans then identify what clusters are created against what labels after this I can then specifically train a naive classifier to pick up the one key component from a specific cluster with alot more certainty and accuracy.